Django some URLs 301ing to home on Production only (NGINX, GUnicorn)
In production, some of my URLs work, some dont and redirect to home / the main site URL.
So, I have a site up and running in Production. I use a NGINX load balancer with 3 x NGINX reverse proxy with GUnicorn VMs running the app. The app includes the following in its URL file:
path("interest/", view=SDInterestView.as_view(template_name="sd/interest.jinja2"), name="sd_intresse"),
path("interesta/", view=SDInterestViewA.as_view(template_name="sd/interest.jinja2"), name="sd_intressea"),
path("interestcopy/", view=SDInterestView.as_view(template_name="sd/interest.jinja2"), name="sd_intresse_copy")

These are base level URLs. so www.site.com/intresse/   etc...
SDInterestView and SDInterestViewA are copy paste code - other than the class name.
So - interest/ works. Neither interesta/ or interestcopy/ work in production. Everything works AOK with RunServer or runserver_plus locally in dev. If I access the back end python session of one of the VMs, I can resolve the URL and see for all three the correct attributes for which view they are going to execture. The three URLs all show in manage.py show_urls.
I am at a loss as to how to track down what the issue is. At the moment I can not see to add in any base level URLs and get them to work. If I add urls to the apps individual URL files, these show and work AOK - but - then do not have the URL path I need.
Any thoughts on how best to debug this issue and work out what is happening. The NGINX load balancer and individual reverse proxies have very basic configs with a single localtion / section. So I am certain it is not this causing the issue.
Thanks for any and all help
I have tried adding debug and logging info to the View class but none of this fires off when the URL for intresesta and interestcopy are envoked.
I have searched for interest/ and interest in the code base in case some middleware or something else has a list of acceptable base urls etc... but no such thing exists.
